# AngularJS ng-class active by any subroute

Tags: angularjs

I have a tab I want to be activated by a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8020/client#/content
```

Therefore I have this list-element:

```
li ng-show="showContentItemsTab" ng-class="{active: isActive('/content')}"><a href="#/list">Content</a></li>
```

But I also want it to be active when sublinks are called:

```
http://localhost:8020/client#/content/531443caeb3f95600ef92e3f
```

Is there a way to apply all sublinks after /content ?

Something like:

```
li ng-show="showContentItemsTab" ng-class="{active: isActive('/content/*')}"><a href="#/list">Content</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the official angular js tutorial, you can set up routing as follows.

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

The controller will be

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers',[]);

    phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
      function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.phone = data;
        });
      }]);
```

So your  can be fetched by using `$routeParams`

Comment: That's familiar. I just wanted to know, if I can apply subroutes to ng-class="{active: isActive('/content')}"

Comment: I want it to be active whatever route comes behind /content ... like content/12312321321